# What object does the $ sign in "function loadGal($) "?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery that I am trying to integrate in my site. I am replacing a  and then I want to call the galleries function  "function loadGal($)" so the gallery will be rebuilt. But I don't know what kind of parameter to send to it.

Before I changed it, it was called inside "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {"

I just tried to do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            loadGal($);
        });
```

it works fine but I don't know what is the dollar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` is just the name of the parameter. It is nothing special. `$` is a valid character of variable names in JavaScript.

However it is often used by libraries such as jQuery or Prototype as it is probably the most characteristic one-letter variable (`j` or `p` don't stand out that much) (meaning it is easy to spot and easy to use as you only have to type one character).

[The value passed to the `ready` handler, is the `jQuery` object](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (emphasis is mine):

> When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call `$.noConflict()` to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the `$` shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write jQuery each time we would normally write `$`. **However, the handler passed to the `.ready()` method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object.** This means we can rename the object within the context of our .`ready()` handler without affecting other code

but you can name the parameter however you want. You could also write:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(foobar) {
    loadGal(foobar);
});
```

**Update:** And now that I understood the real question ;)

`$` is the `jQuery` object, so you can write:

```
loadGal(jQuery);
```

But note that `loadGal` might not work if it has to work on the DOM elements and you call it outside the `ready` handler.

Comment: my question is what kind of object it is. I know it's an object. But in order to call it myself, outside of the jQuery(document).ready(function($) I need to place something here: loadGal(??????);

Comment: @Gal Miller: Ah I see. I have written in my answer, that it is the `jQuery` object. So you would have to write `loadGal(jQuery)`.

Comment: When the global $ for jQuery isn't available, it can be used in a local scope by doing this:  `(function($) { /* ... */ })(jQuery);`, which is essentially passing the global `jQuery` object to the function as its `$` parameter.

Comment: @Felix It is an argument, not a parameter.

Comment: @Sime Vidas They're often used synonymously, but if you want to be pedantic about it, it's called a parameter in the function definition and an argument in the function call. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_science)#Parameters_and_arguments

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Are we being nitpicky? ;) :D Is *parameter* the official term in JavaScript? Because I think you *can* use both names can be used interchangeably. At least Wikipedia says that *parameter* is used in function (procedure) definitions (but of course the big W does not need to be right here, just trying to find some support for my term ;))

Comment: @Felix As @Wiseguy summed it up, there is a clear distinction. I didn't know that people are using them interchangeably.

Comment: @Felix: I believe you had it right. `$` is an identifier that is a member of the *FormalParameterList* for the function. Arguments are the values passed to a function call and the [[ParameterMap]] is the internal property that maps the members of the Arguments object to the formal parameters.